# Laravel one to many relation Property [jadwal_poliklinik] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: laravel, eloquent, one-to-many

Can Anybody help me with Laravel Relationship ?
i have data base structure

```
   poliklinik Table
   ===========
   id
   nama_poliklinik
   ****************

   jadwal_poliklinik Table
   =======================
   id
   poliklinik_id
   hari
   ***********************
```

the relationship is "One" polikinik "have many" jadwal_poliklinik

my model poliklinik is

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\jadwal_poliklinik;

class poliklinik extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'poliklinik';

    public function jadwal_poliklinik()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(jadwal_poliklinik::class);
    }
}
```

my jadwal_poliklinik model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\poliklinik;

class jadwal_poliklinik extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'jadwal_poliklinik';

    public function poliklinik()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(poliklinik::class);
    }

}
```

my controller is

```
public function jadwal()
    {
        $poliklinik = poliklinik::all();

        return view('jadwal', compact('poliklinik'));
    }
```

and the view

```
            <div class="row">
                @foreach($poliklinik as $p)
                <div class="col-md-4 animate-box">
                    <div class="blog-entry">
                        <a href="blog.html" class="blog-img" style="background-image: url(images/blog-1.jpg);"></a>
                        <div class="desc">
                            <h3>{{$p->nama_poliklinik}}</h3>
                            <hr/>
                            @foreach($poliklinik->jadwal_poliklinik as $jp)
                            {{$jp->hari}}<br/>
                            @endforeach
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                @endforeach
            </div>
```

but result is

> Exception Property [jadwal_poliklinik] does not exist on this
>   collection instance.

can someone help me with this??

Comment: `@foreach($p->jadwal_poliklinik as $jp)`

Comment: As a side note, eager load your relationship to avoid `n+1` SQL queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must be `$p->jadwal_poliklinik`

```
@foreach($p->jadwal_poliklinik as $jp)
      {{$jp->hari}}<br/>
 @endforeach
```

But also, Its better if you can use CamelCase for class names. That is the standard. You can simply use artisan command to create classes. See the bellow link for more details.

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#defining-models